# SwiftUI: ObservableObject not updating other view

Tags: swiftui, observable

I have two views:

```
struct Login: View {
    @ObservedObject var Namespace = namespace()
    Button(action: {
                Namespace.changeNamespace(spacename: "Whatever")
                       }) {
                            Text("Change name")
                        }

    ...
}
```

and

```
 struct Main: View {
    @ObservedObject var Namespace = namespace()
    Button(action: {
                Namespace.changeNamespace(spacename: "Whatever")
                       }) {
                            Text("Change name")
                        }
            Text("Namespace: \(Namespace.name)")

    ...
   
    }
```

I also have the object itself:

```
class namespace: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var name = String()

    ...
    func changeNamespace(spacename:String){
         self.name = spacename
     }
   
}
```

I observe the following:

When I hit the button on the Main View, the text on the Main View changes (expected behavior)

However, if I hit the button on the Login View, the text on the Main View doesn't change.

In a way that makes sense, since the Namespace objects in either view are separate instances of a 'namespace' object, but I thought the whole purpose of observable objects is that a change of such object would be reflected by all views that are observing this object.

In short:

I want to change an object in View A, so that View B will be redrawn.

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply `@ObservedObject` to other views using `environmentObject` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/environmentobject(_:)):

```
struct ViewA: View {
    @ObservedObject var nameSpace = NameSpace()
    var body: some View {
     ...
     ViewB().environmentObject(nameSpace)
     ...
     }
}
```

then in ViewB

```
struct ViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var nameSpace: NameSpace
    var body: some View {
     ...
     Text("Namespace: \(nameSpace.name)")
     ...
     }
}
```